# When is it safe to call getListView() in a ListFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I'm trying to set the background of a single row in a list view. Eventually I want the user to be able to pick their own image for each row and set the background of it. I've tried the following...

```
getListView().getChildAt(0).setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.notecard_background));
```

In `onStart()`,`onViewCreated()`, and `onResume()`. In all of these methods, the call above returns a `null` View. When I use that same line of code in `onListItemClick()`, it works fine. I figured that `onViewCreated()` would be the best place to do this as. the view should be created. What's going on here? Why am I only able to get a child view from a `ListView` in `onListItemClick()`? Rather, why can I not get it in `onViewCreated()` or any method that is supposed to be called after that one such as `onStart()` and `onResume()`?

Edit:

My adapter is being set in

```
 public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
       if(savedInstanceState!=null){
           setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("cNames")));
       }else{
           setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,parentSubject.getCardNames()));
       }
     //the line below returns null for getChildAt()
     //  getListView().getChildAt(0).setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.notecard_background));
    }
```

Edit 2:

Ended up creating my own adapter and get a handle to the list item views there. I'd still like to know what was going on up above.

```
public class CardListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Cards>{

    private Activity context;


    public CardListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Cards> cards) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId,cards);

        this.context=(Activity)context;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            TextView tv=(TextView)context.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        }

        Cards item = getItem(position);
        if (item!= null) {
            // My layout has only one TextView
            TextView itemView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text);
            if (itemView != null) {
                itemView.setText(item.getCardFront());
                itemView.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.notecard_background));
            }
         }

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's based on where you are setting the `Adapter` to `LilstView`?

Comment: I'm setting in on onViewCreated

Comment: have you tried in `onActivityCreated()` callback?

Comment: Just tried, did not work.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not the right way to do it. You should create your own `Adapter` and override the `getView()` method to change the background of the row in there.